# Get to home page only through login/signup

Tags: django

My task is to get home page view only after login/signup action. For example, if we go to example.com we should get login page. And if we are not registered before then pushing Login button (after entering any username and password because at the moment I have not done yet Signup button) have to move us at signup page.

Here the code is:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm

def my_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

                else:
                    # Return a 'disabled account' error message
                    pass
            else:
                # send to signup
                return render(request, 'signup.html', {})
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

And this is my login.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'my_login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

Currently the error is shown (after hiting Login button) -

> ValueError at /login/
>   The view evr.views.my_login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

But the point is not only about this error. I am just do not understand in general if my direction is right or not?

Comment: Since the error is in your login view, you should perhaps show it, don't you think?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: I put my code at http://pastebin.com/e5LCJmgH .. or is it obligatory to put code here only?

Comment: You need to put the code *relevant to your error* in your question; links die. You should also include what you have tried and researched to solve the problem so far.

Comment: ok.. I've put the code here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login url has two possible paths that currently don't return a response, so you need to decide what needs showing when:

- The form isn't valid
- The user isn't active

All views **must** return a response object